# What Solr type fits best the following arbitrary data keys

Tags: javascript, solr, schema

So we have been using schemaless mode of solr, and now going to production and thinking this might cause problems. One thing seems a problem already (doubtfully), is the very big schema we have.

## Data

We have some strongly typed field which are fine, but we have a sub doc we want to index which has the following format:

`...({ power_point: 5, word: 10, excel: 2, ... })`

so this obviously results to a very big schema.

What would be a type to mitigate this while having good performance. I know that definitely we would lose keys as fields to search with.

I also know about dynamic fields, something like:

`<dynamicField name="*_exp" type="int" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>`
while inserting the actual data:
`...({ power_point_exp: 5, word_exp: 10, excel_exp: 2, ... })`

But this also grows schema infinitely.

Is Solr able to simply index something like:

`{experiences: { power_point: 5, word: 10, excel: 2, ...}}`

Comment: What kind of queries are you looking to match against the field? That will dictate how you can index and process the field, since it'll have to match how you want to search it - i.e. whether you can combine the values into a single key (if you only want to query for the exact numeric value, you can just have `experiences` as a `string` field and index `power_point|5` or a similar value). Also the field cardinality will be interesting; how many different keys (power_point, word, etc.) are you looking at?

Comment: the string cardinality is important, this is why at first place it was indexed. But if no solution is present for growing schema and errors that might arise (same key with different type or something), we will be obliged to scarify that. The idea of indexing experiences as `experiences: ["power_point|5", "word|10"]` seems fine. I didn't think of that. For querying we are using a simple weight on static field, but as `*:*` so it also includes every other dynamically added fields.

Comment: In terms of how are user queries; I think at first, functionally it was thought as the following: user can look for arbitrary text everywhere in database, but can be more intelligent and look for something like `power_point:*`

Comment: The main problem with indexing `power_point|5` is that if the numeric value can be large and you want to perform range searches, you'll have to decide now what range you can support, then expand the number into having enough digits to cover the range. If the value is from 0 to 10 (or 0 to 100000, etc - as long as it's well defined), then you're fine. Index `power_point|0005` to get 0-9999 as the range - that way you can do range searches as `experience:[power_point|0005 TO power_point|0200]` for example (since the tokens will sort properly)

Comment: Searching for `experience:power_point|*` will give you any entries (you might have to escape `|` to get it to behave properly) with power point experience; however, if that is a common query, I'd just have another field with `experience_categories` as well, where `power_point`, `word`, `excel` as direct entries as well - which you can then use for faceting to allow people to facet for anyone that have power_point as an experience category.

Comment: at first I didn't think of `power_point|5` with `|` as meaningful.  So now I understand that Solr even indexes that as a number, which is very strong ! great. I think this is a good option we will consider. thanks a lot, as this is a complete answer.
One last thing, do you mean arbitrary data as `experiences: ["power_point|5", "word|10", "blablabla|55]` will get indexed and could be queried as you said ? (I can test this when I can though) thanks a lot

Comment: If you use one of the payload filters you can attach the `5` part as a numeric value to the token and use it for multiple purposes, but you shouldn't have to do that in this case. It'll need to be a string field - not a text field - otherwise you'll get `"power_point|5", "excel|10"` to match against `power_point|10`, since they'll be split into separate tokens (so `power_point`, `5`, `excel`, `10`). If you send a list you'll have to define a multivalued field which will hold multiple, separate tokens, and if using exact matching (as a string field would), you'd only get identical hits.